Microsoft Power Apps Choice Column from SP List Date Formatting
I'm trying to populate a dropdown box on a power apps customized sharepoint list form with dates from a column in the same list, filtered by the Employee (people picker) that is in the current form.
I'm using the following for the Items property:
Filter('My List', Employee.DisplayName=DataCardValue2.Selected.DisplayName).StartDate
This does populate the drop down, but the values are shown as Epoch time. I know how to use math to convert it, but since the result is a table column, I can't figure out how to convert all the returned values over to a normal format (preferably yyyy-mm-dd)
You can't simply wrap it all in a Text() function, since that doesn't work on table columns only strings. So how can I get these values into the format I want?
Bonus question: how would I get it to populate the dropdown values as StartDate AND EndDate concatenated together?

I managed to work it out with some help on Discord.
AddColumns(Filter('My List', Employee.DisplayName=DataCardValue2.Selected.DisplayName), concatColumn, Employee.DisplayName & " " & StartDate & " to " & EndDate).concatColumn
